# SVN checkout gives me error E175002

Tags: svn

I am trying to checkout a remote svn repo. [This](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/branches/ytex) is the link for the repo. When I do

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/branches/ytex ctakes
```

it proceeds for a while and then I get

> svn: E175002: REPORT of '/repos/asf/!svn/me': Could not read response body: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.apache.org)

How do I fix this? Please help.

Feel free to try it yourself and let me know. :)

EDIT : Is there any other way I can clone that repo to my local?

Comment: I sometimes see this when the server's connection to the Internet is flaky or overloaded.  The only solution I know is to try again later.  :(

Comment: What `svn` client version do you have?

Comment: @bahrep svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Oct 15 2013, 12:40:34

Comment: @zack I'm getting client-side crash when doing checkout using `svn` 1.8.9 client. Looking at this further...

Comment: @bahrep are you doing svn checkout on the repo I mentioned?

Comment: If so, I seemed to have boiled down the error to [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ctakes/branches/ytex/ctakes-dependency-parser-res/src/main/resources/org/apache/ctakes/dependency/parser/models/) link. If you try downloading/checking out "clearparser_model.jar" the download gets hung up half way. Unfortunately I haven't yet found a workaround for that.

Comment: @zack yep, I checkout the same repo and get different errors and a crash. It could be that there are some temporarily connectivity problems with the ASF repository right now. However, I'm concerned about the crash.

Comment: @bahrep yes. Likewise. I believe the error is the clearparser_mode.jar file. Whatever the case is, if you manage to get it to work, please let me know.